# uEye Camera can't open device

Tags: c#, camera, device

I'm using API uEye camera for an application and I have trouble to init my camera.

First time I run my application (with Visual Studio in Debug) the application run fine, the camera is on. I'm still developing, then I run and quit many times.  But after some tests (sometimes 1, sometimes 10), the camera doesn't initiate. I had to quit visual studio and re open to make the camera run.

My code for init:

```
uEye.Camera _cam;
_cam = new uEye.Camera();
if (_cam != null)
{
    _cam.Exit();
}

uEye.Defines.Status statusRet = 0;
_cam.EventDeviceRemove += EventDeviceRemove;

statusRet = _cam.Init(DeviceNumber | (int)uEye.Defines.DeviceEnumeration.UseDeviceID, 0);
if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
    throw new Exception("Camera initializing failed. init return " + (int)statusRet);
```

When the camera doesn't run I have `statusRet == uEye.Defines.Status.CANT_OPEN_DEVICE`.

What can I do to correctly initiate camera every times ?

Edit:

There is my `Stop` method, called when application is closing:

```
public void Stop()
{
    _cam.EventFrame -= NewFrameArrived;
    _cam.Acquisition.Stop(uEye.Defines.DeviceParameter.Wait);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_cam != null)
    {
        _cam.Exit();
        _cam = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure you're freeing up all uses of the camera if it probably works 1 time and not others?

Comment: `_cam` cannot be `null` after `_cam = new ...`, this is impossible in C#. Also, check that you call the `Exit()` method and unsubscribe from all the events. We have no troubles with an uEye camera.

Comment: @BugFinder edit added, there is my code called when main windows is closing. But i'm in debug, sometimes I don't quit "properly"  and I press the Quit Debug button. Is there a way to check at init if all uses are released ?
@dymanoid Exit and unsubscribe are correctly called, I removed the useless `if (_cam != null)`

Comment: @A.Pissicat On closing the program, you must release/unitialise the camera. That could be an issue. Or before initializing check the status of camera. if offline then initialize or else do not.

Comment: I've tried this, but there is no way to know if I had correctly released the camera on close. And I can't get the status of camera in initialization, I only had a status `uEye.Defines.Status.CANT_OPEN_DEVICE`. I wonder if there is a way to have more details ?

Comment: Do you actively call dispose? If not, try to put _cam.Exit() in part of the code where you can be absolutly sure _cam.Exit() is called before application is closed.